# Resetting a BIOS password on a laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords

I bought a ChemBook laptop which I have installed Ubuntu Linux on.  It has an AMI BIOS.  There is a password on the BIOS so I can not change its configuration.  The laptop does not have a 3.5inch floppy.  How do I reset or remove the BIOS password so I can access it and make my own changes and set up my own password?

Comment: Some notebooks can be reset by removing AC, Main battery, then cmos battery for several minutes, others have the password stored on a separate chip that cannot be reset by this procedure, in that case you will need to try some known softwares or known master passwords as suggested below, or pay a service to get it done.

Answer (score 7):

Removing the battery tends to be a PITA for laptops, so here's some other to try first:

Check [Here](http://www.tech-faq.com/reset-bios-password.html) for some methods... maybe one of the backdoor pw will work.

Or try [CmosPwd](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/CmosPwd)

Comment: cmospwd is the easiest place to start

Answer (score 3):

You will need to remove the bios battery on the motherboard and let the capacitors drain before you put the battery back in (give it about 60 seconds or so), this will reset the bios and remove the password. I am not sure how easy this is on that given laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Pull out the ram. remove the battery on the motherboard. Press and hold the power button down for maybe 30 seconds (with battery and plug removed) and it should clear it.